# Como escrever um arquivo tabular em uma instância do Azure Data Lake Store com a API Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-azure

Suponha que eu tenho uma instância do Data Lake Store na minha inscrição Azure e que eu gostaria de criar um script em Python para escrever um arquivo tabular com separador (do tipo CSV ou similares) nessa instância.

Sem considerar a API Spark, como eu posso fazer para escrever esse arquivo tabular na instância do Data Lake Store usando a API Python de escrever arquivos?

Comment: Por favor administradores, gostaria de sugerir a criação da tag "azure-data-lake-store", visto a existência de outros domínios particulares do Azure já criados, como o "azure-devops". O Azure Data Lake Store é talvez um dos recursos mais importantes do Azure hoje em dia.

Answer (score 0):

Não uso o Azure, então me perdoe caso não seja relevante: vou responder como escrever dados em um arquivo CSV usando Python3.x.

Vale mencionar antes que a maioria das bibliotecas inclui um método para converter para CSV diretamente, como o [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) e o [Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file). Possivelmente (estou especulando, sim) você pode redirecionar seu dado em Python de volta para o ambiente Azure e utilizar uma ferramenta nativa.

Um exemplo simples de como escrever um arquivo CSV, usando Python:

```
import csv
lista = ['Alice','Bob','Carlos']
lista2 = ['Xavier','Yago','Zulmira']

with open('nomes.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    namewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    namewriter.writerow(lista)
    namewriter.writerow(lista2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Rocchi, é uma resposta válida mas no Azure Data Lake Store, por ser um sistemas de arquivos distribuído, existem algumas limitações para se escrever diretamente com a API do Python dessa forma, já que essa API não entende o sistema de arquivos distribuído por traz desse tipo de sistema como faz, por exemplo, o Spark.

Comment: Entendo. E é possível você sair da execução do script Python carregando os dados que você precisa? Por exemplo. Uma vez precisei escrever um script Bash e fazer cálculos que não eram suportados, então dentro do script Bash eu iniciava um script Python igualando ele a uma variável. Após a execução, a variável estava carregando o dado de saída do script Python. Em outras palavras: você pode tentar igualar o resultado da execução do script Python a uma variável no outro ambiente (PowerShell??).